# How to make number operation in js replace function?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

```
const detailFontSize = fontSize ? fontSize.replace(/(\d+)/, $1-2) : '';
```

For example, fontSize is "12pt", and I hope to modify it to "10pt". How to make the number operation in replace function with $1？

Codes above do not work since $1 is not defined. and if I add quotes, it will become to "12-2pt"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a function as a second argument of the .replace() to manipulate matched value:

```js
const fontSize = '12pt';

const detailFontSize = fontSize ? fontSize.replace(/(\d+)/, m => Number(m) - 2) : '';

console.log(detailFontSize)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use a var to store the value like `a = /(\d+)/.exec(fontSize)` and then chck if `a is null`, if no then `(parseInt(a[0]) - 2) + 'pt'`; finally, assign the calculated value to the target